# Understanding FFT size in OFDM

Tags: fft, ofdm, ifft

The number of subcarriers = the size of the FFT?

The size may be the same or different depending on the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of subcarriers including the null carriers is the size of the FFT since the complex value for each FFT bin represents the subcarrier modulation symbol (as a QAM waveform for example). You can also oversample by zero-padding out the FFT after subcarrier mapping to a larger FFT.

Comment: Thanks.                                                            That is, with oversampling: FFT size > number of subcarriers (including null carriers).                  Please tell me what are the benefits of oversampling?

Comment: Oversampling in the transmitter allows for simpler analog filters after the D/A converter.  It is also necessary to implement predistortion algorithms. (For operating power amplifiers further into compression resulting in better power efficiency- to the extent the power saved overcomes the power loss by sampling at a higher rate).